# Contact open FDA information

Tags: openfda

We are a team from Asia Taiwan. This center, based in Taiwan, aims to promote international police cooperation and enhance law enforcement capabilities through scientific research and technological innovation.
We sent a email to open@fda.hhs.gov. However, we still did not respond from open FDA team.  We are looking forward to hearing from you this week.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We'll have an answer for you shortly - apologies for the delay.

Regards,

Violet Wren

openFDA Tech Lead